# $\mathbf{x}$ and $\mathbf{y}$ are orthogonal if and only if $\lVert \mathbf{x} + \lambda \mathbf{y}\rVert \geq \lVert \mathbf{x} \rVert$

Tags: calculus, inequality

Let $\mathbf{x}, \mathbf{y} \in \mathbb{R}^n$ non zero vectors. Show that $\mathbf{x}$ and $\mathbf{y}$ are orthogonal if and only if
$$
\lVert \mathbf{x} + \lambda \mathbf{y} \rVert \geq \lVert \mathbf{x} \rVert 
$$
for all $\lambda \in \mathbb{R}$. Please help me, I have absolutely no idea on how to even begin.

Comment: Try squaring both sides?

Comment: Intuitively, $\mathbf{x}+\lambda\mathbf{y}$ is a line, starting from $\mathbf{x}$ with the direction of $\mathbf{y}$. The shortest distance between this line and the origin becomes $\lVert\mathbf{x}\rVert$ when $\mathbf{x}$ and $\mathbf{y}$ are orthogonal.

Answer (score 1):

First, note that, if $\mathbf{a} = \left( a_1, \ldots, a_n \right)$ and $\mathbf{b} = \left( b_1, \ldots, b_n \right)$ be any vectors in $\mathbb{R}^n$, then their dot (or inner) product is given by
$$
\mathbf{a} \cdot \mathbf{b} \mbox{ or } \langle \mathbf{a}, \mathbf{b} \rangle = a_1 b_1 + \cdots + a_n b_n. 
$$

Let $\mathbf{v} = \left( v_1, \ldots, v_n \right)$ be any vector in $\mathbb{R}^n$. Then we have
$$
\lVert \mathbf{v} \rVert^2 = v_1^2 + \cdots + v_n^2 = \mathbf{v} \cdot \mathbf{v} \mbox{ or } \langle \mathbf{v}, \mathbf{v} \rangle.
$$

Using the above definitions, we can show that
$$
\lVert \mathbf{x} + \lambda \mathbf{y} \rVert^2 = \lVert \mathbf{x} \rVert^2 + 2 \lambda \langle \mathbf{x}, \mathbf{y} \rangle + \lambda^2 \lVert \mathbf{y} \rVert^2. \tag{1}
$$
Now $\mathbf{x}$ and $\mathbf{y}$ are orthogonal if and only if $\langle \mathbf{x}, \mathbf{y} \rangle = 0$, and using (1) above this in turn holds if and only if
$$
\lVert \mathbf{x} + \lambda \mathbf{y} \rVert^2 = \lVert \mathbf{x} \rVert^2 + \lambda^2 \lVert \mathbf{y} \rVert^2 \geq \lVert \mathbf{x} \rVert^2, 
$$
that is,
$$
\lVert \mathbf{x} + \lambda \mathbf{y} \rVert^2 \geq \lVert \mathbf{x} \rVert^2,
$$
which holds if and only if
$$
\lVert \mathbf{x} + \lambda \mathbf{y} \rVert \geq \lVert \mathbf{x} \rVert.
$$

Hope this helps. Please feel free to ask for any further clarification as needed.

Comment: And how do I prove the second implication?

Comment: @Roma_Rayado He said "if and only if"

Answer (score -1):

$\|X+\lambda Y\|=(X+\lambda Y,X+\lambda Y)=(X,X)+2\lambda(Y, X)+\lambda^2(Y,Y)\geq(X,X)$
Which only holds for all $\lambda$ iff (X,Y)=0